# Set default-directory relative to the place an Elisp function is defined

Tags: shell-command, directory

I have some custom elisp functions that need to run shell scripts using `shell-command`. I would like to use a relative path to the script, e.g.:

```
(shell-command "./run.sh")
```

rather than an absolute one:

```
(shell-command "~/blah/blah/blah/run.sh")
```

But the relative path will only work if the working directory contains the script. I don't want to use an absolute path, because the path to the shell script might change. However, the shell script will always be in the same directory as the `.el` file where the function is defined, so I thought I could leverage that fact, and use a relative path instead, I just can't figure out how to do it. I know that I can change the `default-directory`, but I don't know how to do that without using an absolute path.

Is there a way for me to tell the function to use the directory that contains its `.el` file as the `default-directory`, or is there maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a variable in the script that records the directory:

```
(defvar my-shell-directory
  (if load-file-name
      (file-name-directory load-file-name)
    default-directory))
```

You can then use it in your own functions:

```
(defun my-shell-command (cmd)
  (shell-command (expand-file-name cmd my-shell-directory)))
```